# Laravel 7 form validation json object

Tags: php, laravel

my request looks like this:

```
array:2 [
  "address" => array:1 [
    "data" => array:1 [
      "street" => ""
    ]
  ]
  "postal_address" => array:1 [
    "data" => array:1 [
      "street" => "random street"
    ]
  ]
]
```

And I want to validate that both streets are required, but I don't know how I can access it in my request I tried like this but It makes a new key and no validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'address.data.street'  => 'required|max:16',
        'postal_address.data.street' => 'required|max:16',
    ];
}
```

It returns a weird formatted object:

```
errors: {
    address.data.street: [
      0: "required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: you code works fine for me using the latest laravel version, it returns: "address.data.street": ["The address.data.street field is required."]

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'address' => 'array',
        'address.data' => 'array',
        'address.data.street' => 'required|max:16',
        'postal_address' => 'array',
        'postal_address.data' => 'array',
        'postal_address.data.street' => 'required|max:16'
    ];
}
```